SvgPicture: border around SVG graphic possible?
I want to be able to set a different color for the border around my SVG image.
Currently I am only able to set the color the image like so:
SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/images/example.svg',
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black, BlendMode.srcIn),
),

Is there a way to draw a border around the image?

Put your expected and actual result image, it more clear to understand

Yes, it's possible to add a border around an SVG graphic in Flutter. I think this is the way you can do this. Wrapping your SVG graphic within a Container widget and setting the decoration property of the Container to include a border.
Here's How you can do this:
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 2.0,
     ),
    ),
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/example.svg',
    ),
),

Adjust height, width and border properties according to your svg image.

I have tried this and it gave me a rectangular border around the non-rectangular svg image. I am looking for a solution that draws around the edges of the svg image. Thank you for your answer though!

Now another way to achieve this is by using a 'CustomPaint' widget along with the 'Path' class to trace the outline of the SVG image and draw a border along it.

Would you mind showing me how to do that? I've never used CustomPaint or Path... Would appreciate it a lot!

I have used CustomPaint once but I think this is also another way to solve your problem.

Okay, so you do not know how that would be done in this given case? It's fine if you don't, but if you do I'd appreciate a short snippet that points me in the right direction!

@StativBus put your expected image and actual image that you want so It will be more clear to understand
